# Laravel model not exist attribute detection

Tags: laravel, exception, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have **User** model with fields:

```
id
name
email
password
```

Why the Laravel does not return an error during the request for a non-existent attribute. How to return an error when a non-existent attribute is requested?

**Code:**

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1);

echo $user->name; // This attribute exist in out table and we can continue...
echo $user->location; // Attribute `location` doesn't defined and we can't continue!!!
```

Comment: It will return null, you can check using `is_null` and return an error if you want.

Comment: How can I do this for all models on an error handler `(Exceptions\Handler.php)` ? @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: This is not an exception, so I do not think you will handle it as exception, but what is the problem you are facing on this situation, let me know, may be I can give some other view to it.

Comment: I just want users which use my application API not to request for non-existing table fields. @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: That you can not take care of like that, yes if they will try to get a model instance or something, they will get 404 but for properties they will always get null.

Comment: In general, it is better not to think about it during API development? @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: You do not need to or if you want to specify it, why not do it in api docs that this model has these properties and not that.

Comment: Can you show how you're users are able to request different table fields? You should realistically use validation for this.

Comment: With this question, you threw me into a dead end. I'd rather not check it out :) @RossWilson

Comment: ??? In not sure what you mean by that? Which bit threw you in to a dead end? :)

Comment: The bit is "Request different table fields" using API ;) @RossWilson

Comment: It's based on your comment "I just want users which use my application API not to request for non-existing table fields". So, I'm assuming that there is something in your code which allows users to select what fields are returned from the API? If so, please can you show this code?

Comment: Yes it is, but after your question, I thought. Api works only with its own rules and some non-existent field cannot change its rule and functionality. I stupidly confused the backend with the API. In the backend itself, you can add non-existent fields from the database, but through api this is not possible, of course, only if the developer takes care of everything. @RossWilson

Answer (score 3):

You can override your model `getAttributeValue` method like below:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...

    public function getAttributeValue($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttributeValue($key);
        if ($value) {
            return $value;
        }
        throw new \Exception("Attribute Does Not Exists!");
    }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can override __get method in model like below code :

```
public function __get($key)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes))
        throw new \Exception("{$key attribute does not defined !!! }", 1);

    return $this->getAttribute($key);
}
```